# Cesium: Dynamically Change Entity Position

Tags: javascript, performance, latitude-longitude, cesiumjs

I'm drawing an entity using position data being fed from a database.

I'm currently using

```
viewer.entities.removeAll();
```

to remove all the entities every time I get a result from the database.

This causes a long and heavy process in the browser as the entities are currently 3D models.

Is there a better way for the data to update, for example an array of the entities.

Or a way to cache the entities that I could then alter the data.

The end result is so that I could alter the positions on the fly and then see the entity update on the display

I am using

```
viewer.entities.add({
            name : name,
            position : position,
            orientation : orientation,
            model : {
                uri : url,
                minimumPixelSize : 50
            }
        });
```

to add the entities

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at the [Picking Demo](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/?src=Picking.html), you can see it assigning new `Cartesian3` values to `entity.position` around line 26 in the live-editor window.  Updating an entity is going to be much faster than destroying it and creating a new one.

Also, if your database knows that an entity has a position that changes over time, you can supply that via a [SampledPositionProperty](https://cesium.com/learn/cesiumjs/ref-doc/SampledPositionProperty.html), and allow Cesium to animate the entity moving along a path over time.

Comment: Awesome, issue is, I can't seem to find the actual entity that I've created after rendering the model.

Comment: Can you post the code that creates the entity?  If you're calling `viewer.entities.add` it should return a reference to the newly created entity.  You can also give the entity a unique ID to look it up.

Comment: Yep, just add `var entity =` in front of `viewer.entities.add` and you have a reference to the entity that you can keep and modify.

Comment: There are many entities, this is in a loop. Is there an array or something in viewer that holds all of them? - i'm a dumbass, just realised what i put

Comment: Your DB must have a primary key or some unique identifier for each one though right?  You can add an `"id" : "some Unique String 123"` to the `viewer.entities.add` block, and look it up again later with `var entity = viewer.entities.getById('some Unique String 123');`

Comment: managed to loop them all and grabbed the id, thanks, will accept as answer :)